# Amazon Linux add user to group

Tags: linux, permissions, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon Linux AMI image doing development. And I want to add the default user 'ec2-user' into group 'docker' like below:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a ec2-user docker
```

When I logged in as user `ec2-user`, and run `groups ec2-user`, it shows:

```
ec2-user : ec2-user wheel docker
```

And this seems to indicate the 'ec2-user' was added to group 'docker'. However, if I run `groups` command without any parameter, which should be the same as `groups ec2-user` because I logged in as `ec2-user`, it shows:

```
ec2-user wheel
```

And it tells me ec2-user is not in the group 'docker' yet (actually it was not added to this group because permission error was reported when I tried to access some file belongs to group 'docker').

And this does not happen if I try to add the 'ec2-user' into group in this way:

```
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
```

And I found I can add other user name like 'harry' into group like below without any problem:

```
sudo gpasswd -a harry docker
```

My question is what is the cause for this behavior? It seems there is something wrong with this particular user name 'ec2-user' when adding it to a group but I have no idea why this happens. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to log out and back in or start a new log-in shell for changes to your group membership to become effective.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen but it is not the case for other users I created such as 'harry' in the example. Once I created use 'harry' and added it into a group using gpasswd command, I can see it added to group immediately without logging out.

Comment: Taking into account the comment, this answer is correct, and deserves to be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The current shell was initialized before you added yourself to the group, so it cannot reflect a later change to your group memberships. You can

```
exec sg docker
```

to replace the current shell with a new one which is explicitly switched to the group you added yourself to, or simply log out and back in.